# Ktor http client - request progress

Tags: kotlin, ktor

How do I monitor request progress in Ktor http client?

For example: I have request like this:

```
val response = HttpClient().get<String>("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

and I want to monitor request progress with progress bar like this:

```
fun progress(downloaded: Long, contentLength: Long) {
    // Update progress bar or whatever
}
```

How do I set `progress()` to be called by HttpClient?

edit: This is Kotlin Multiplatform project. Relevant dependencies are:

```
implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.2.5'
implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.2.5'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Ktor 1.6.0, you can react to download progress change using the [onDownload](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.features/on-download.html) extension function exposed by `HttpRequestBuilder`:

```kotlin
val channel = get<ByteReadChannel>("https://ktor.io/") {
    onDownload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
        println("Received $bytesSentTotal bytes from $contentLength")
    }
}
```

There is also the [onUpload](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.features/on-upload.html) function that can be used to display upload progress:

```kotlin
onUpload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
    println("Sent $bytesSentTotal bytes from $contentLength")
}
```

Here are runnable examples from the Ktor documentation:

- [download-file](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/main/codeSnippets/snippets/client-download-file)
- [upload-file](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/main/codeSnippets/snippets/client-upload-file)

Answer (score 1):

How to emit the download progress into a Flow?

I want to observe the download progress by a Flow, so I write a function like this:

```
suspend fun downloadFile(file: File, url: String): Flow<Int>{
        val client = HttpClient(Android)
        return flow{
            val httpResponse: HttpResponse = client.get(url) {
                onDownload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
                    val progress = (bytesSentTotal * 100f / contentLength).roundToInt()
                    emit(progress)
                }
            }
            val responseBody: ByteArray = httpResponse.receive()
            file.writeBytes(responseBody)
        }
}
```

but the `onDownload` will be called only once. If I remove the  `emit(progress)` it will work.

@andrey-aksyonov